# Spring Kafka | How to make DeserializationException retryable?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-retry

I have a Producer that sends messages in **Avro** format and a Consumer which listens to those messages.

I have also implemented non-blocking retries by using `@RetryableTopic` in my Consumer for handling errors.

When the Consumer is unable to deserialize a message (due to schema change or whatever reasons), it does not put that message in the `-retry` topic. It directly sends it to the `-dlt` topic instead.

I want `DeserializationException`s to be retried as well. Reason is that by the time these errors are retried, I can deploy a fix in my Consumer so that the retries could eventually succeed.

I tried the `include` option in `@RetryableTopic` but it doesn't seem to work for `DeserializationException`.

```java
  @RetryableTopic(
    attempts = "${app.consumer.retry.topic.count:5}",
    backoff = @Backoff(delayExpression = "${app.consumer.retry.topic.back-off:2000}"),
    fixedDelayTopicStrategy = FixedDelayStrategy.SINGLE_TOPIC,
    include = {DeserializationException.class}  // does not work
  )
```

Is it a bug in `@RetryableTopic` or is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `Spring Kafka 2.8.3` there's a set of [global fatal exceptions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#retry-topic-ex-classifier) that, as you described, will cause the record to be forwarded to the `DLT` directly.

The usual pattern to handle this kind of exception is, after the fix has been deployed, have some kind of console application to retrieve the failed record from the `DLT` and reprocess it, perhaps by sending the record back to the first retry topic so that there's no duplicate in the main topic.

For the pattern you described, you can manage this global set of `FATAL` exceptions by providing a `DestinationTopicResolver` bean, such as:

```java
@Bean(name = RetryTopicInternalBeanNames.DESTINATION_TOPIC_CONTAINER_NAME)
public DestinationTopicResolver topicResolver(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    DefaultDestinationTopicResolver ddtr = new DefaultDestinationTopicResolver(Clock.systemUTC(), applicationContext);
    ddtr.removeClassification(DeserializationException.class);
    return ddtr;
}
```

Please let me know if that works for you. Thanks.

Comment: Sadly it does not work correctly. It sends the failed message to the retry topic just once and after that it directly sends it to DLT. But most importantly removeNotRetryableException() method is deprecated in 2.8.5

Comment: 2022-04-25 11:15:20.589 ERROR 91937 --- [r#1-retry-0-C-1] k.r.DeadLetterPublishingRecovererFactory : Record: topic = books-retry, partition = 0, offset = 1, main topic = books threw an error at topic books-retry and won't be retried. Sending to DLT with name books-dlt.

Comment: Can you please suggest any alternate approach?

Comment: Sure, sorry, we should update the docs on that. You should use the removeClassification() method instead. The classification removal worked though since it’s not going straight to the DLT anymore. How many attempts are you setting it to?

Comment: Thank you. It is working fine now. One downside is that I have to add every exception to be included in a separate line :) Shouldn't the "include" option in @RetryableTopic support this? It would be good if you can add it in the annotation itself rather than having to create a custom config.

Comment: I’m glad to hear it worked. If you can please accept this as the answer it’ll help other users find it. Those are different classifications - the one I mentioned is specifically for global fatal exceptions. The per-topic classification in the annotation should still work normally for every other exceptions. Is that what you are referring to?

Comment: Sure Tomaz. I agree with your point about the annotation but what I feel is the documentation of "include" option can have a bit more detail. People can get confused like me. May be you can add a little detail saying "The global fatal exceptions will not be retried". https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/api/org/springframework/kafka/annotation/RetryableTopic.html#include()

Comment: Sure, makes sense, we should add that, thanks. Would you be willing to open an issue in the project’s GitHub for that? https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues You can also provide a PR if you’d like. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, I think now I get what you meant - being able to override the fatal classification straight in the topics’ annotation instead of in the component. At first I’m not sure that would be great since you’d have to do that for every topic - I believe it’s better to handle it once in the proper place. But we can keep that in mind for the future. Agree 100% with documenting the behavior though. Thanks again for bringing this up.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant :) Thanks for keeping a note of it. I will create a documentation issue and provide a PR as well later today. Thanks for your prompt help!

Answer (score 2):

Here is how we have achieved it:

```java
  @Bean(name = RetryTopicInternalBeanNames.DESTINATION_TOPIC_CONTAINER_NAME)
  public DestinationTopicResolver destinationTopicResolver(ApplicationContext context) {
    DefaultDestinationTopicResolver resolver = new DefaultDestinationTopicResolver(systemUTC(), context);
    resolver.setClassifications(emptyMap(), true);
    return resolver;
  }
```

This way we don't have to specify every exception to be included one by one. Another solution is as suggested by Tomaz:

```java
  @Bean(name = RetryTopicInternalBeanNames.DESTINATION_TOPIC_CONTAINER_NAME)
  public DestinationTopicResolver topicResolver(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    DefaultDestinationTopicResolver ddtr = new DefaultDestinationTopicResolver(systemUTC(), applicationContext);
    ddtr.removeClassification(DeserializationException.class);
    ddtr.removeClassification(ClassCastException.class);
    return ddtr;
  }
```

Comment: If your goal is to disable FATAL classification for all default fatal exceptions, you don’t need the defaultFalse method - just use the setClassification method with the empty map instead.